# Submit button goes to white screen

Tags: php, html

I have made a contact form and when clicking submit with the form fully filled out the screen just goes white, The link on the page changes from contact.html to contactform.php.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $subject = $_POST['subject'];
      $mailFrom = $_POST['mail'];
      $message = $_POST['message'];

      $mailTo = "email@outlook.com";
      $headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;
      $txt = "You have received an email from ".$name.".\n\n".$message;

      mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers);
      header("Location: index.php?mailsend");
    }
?>

<div>
  <img src="images/contact.jpg" alt="" class="background-contact">

  <div class="contact-box">
    <br>
    <p class="contact-text-tp">Email</p>

      <form class="contact-form" action="contactform.php" method="post">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full name">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Your email">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
        <br>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" name="Submit">Send email</button>
      </form>
      <br>
    <p class="contact-text-btm">If you would like to directly email please use; <br> email@outlook.com</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I would expect that once the 'Send email' button has been pressed to send the email and remain on contact page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP's white screen of death](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death)

Comment: @misorude No His coding is wrong.

Comment: Is the code from `contact.html` or `contactform.php`?

Comment: contact.html is where is have built the form that you will type into and the contactform.php is where the php code is for submitting the email

Comment: So from what file the code in your question? It's just that, the php and the html code are both inside a single file based from the question, yet the php code is supposed to be in `contactform.php` while the html code is in `contact.html`

Answer (score 1):

So first you need to rename the page from `contact.html` to `contact.php` and change your code like the following

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $subject = $_POST['subject'];
      $mailFrom = $_POST['mail'];
      $message = $_POST['message'];

      $mailTo = "email@outlook.com";
      $headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;
      $txt = "You have received an email from ".$name.".\n\n".$message;

      if(mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers)){
         echo 'success';
      }else{
        echo 'failure';
      }
    }
?>

<div>
  <img src="images/contact.jpg" alt="" class="background-contact">

  <div class="contact-box">
    <br>
    <p class="contact-text-tp">Email</p>

      <form class="contact-form" action="" method="post">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full name">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Your email">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
        <br>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" name="Submit">Send email</button>
      </form>
      <br>
    <p class="contact-text-btm">If you would like to directly email please use; <br> email@outlook.com</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: So I have tried this and what SancoLgates advised and still getting white screen

Answer (score 1):

change your

```
<button type="submit" name="Submit">Send email</button>
```

into

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" >
```

please note that you need to pass value in submit to trigger the isset

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code on one page, just save page with "**.php**".

Ex : contact_form.php